# Hide/float half of the UITableView header

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, parallax

I am trying to add something like a parallax effect to my tableview. I have a tableview header (not header for section, but for the whole tableview). The whole header looks like this:

[image]

I want to have this effect - hiding the top half of the header:

[image]

But as you know, if I scroll the tableview, the whole header is hiding behind the navigation bar. How can I achieve this effect? I was trying to add some content insets, but its not working. Thank you in advance!

Comment: if you have only one section you can set the icons you have in the section header, which will stay at the top of the screen

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but I want to have the same background image. With your solution I have the section header, but its transparent without the background. I am also trying find a solution for this, so both table header and section header share the same background image.